# How to bring Neo4j Sandbox project data (Russian Twitter Trolls) directly to Neo4j Desktop on my local laptop

Tags: twitter, neo4j, neo4j-browser

I am wondering if there is a way to bring the sample projects and data on Neo4j Sandbox to Neo4j Desktop on my local laptop?

I am very interested the Russian Twitter Trolls data and want to play around with it on my Neo4j Desktop.

If no, I am wondering if there is anywhere I can find the queries and raw dataset of creating Russian Twitter Trolls dataset on Neo4j Sandbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find the same but I didn't find Raw data and queries.
I think that's not available publically (might be but we don't know where it is).

You can ask for a link on the [Neo4j community page](https://community.neo4j.com/).

I wanted the same but didn't get any response, I found the URL for the same by some trial and error method :)

It's available [HERE](https://s3.amazonaws.com/neo4j-sandbox-usecase-datastores/v3_4/twitter-trolls.db.zip).

Comment: Thank you Raj, have you tried to import this to Neo4j? I also came across this: https://www.lyonwj.com/2017/11/12/scraping-russian-twitter-trolls-python-neo4j/

Comment: Yeah, I have successfully imported this to Neo4j.  Do you need any help?

Comment: Thanks for asking Raj, I am wondering what have you used to load it into Neo4j. I never loaded database like this to Neo4j before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189849/discussion-between-raj-and-mmaass).